# C++11 Pass simple object to a method that receives a container of objects

Tags: c++11

Is it possible to pass a single object to a method that accepts a container of objects?

E.g.:

I have a custom class `Entry` bound to a table from a database:

```
class Entry
{
public:
    Entry(int64_t iId, const std::string &sName);    
    int64_t id();    
    std::string name();

private:
    int64_t iId_;
    std::string sName_;
}

void insert(const std::vector<Entry> &entries)
{
    // For the sake of example
    session.start();
    session << "INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Name) VALUES " << bind(entries);
    session.stop();
}

void function()
{
    Entry entry(1, "RandomName");

    insert( ? entry ? ); // What should I do here?
}
```

Is this possible without instantiating a new container for only one object or without overriding the `insert` method for receiving a simple object?

Comment: Either you must change (or overload) the function, or provide what it expects. There isn't really another choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a braced-init-list.

```
insert( { entry } );
```

The list can convert to the `vector` type, and specifies a container with one element.

Comment: +1 for awesome ha.  I never realized it will do that conversion for you, this is a much better solution than mine.  btw for those interested this link will tell you more about the limits of the conversions it will do:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: Can this be extrapolated to other container types?

Answer (score 0):

You as Quentin mentioned, you really only have 2 options here:

1) overload the function.  So create another function with the signature `void insert(Entry* single_entry)` and create a SQL query to insert only one.

or

2) when you create a new entry via `Entry entry(1, "RandomName")` create a vector with a size of 1 and pass that to your `insert` function.